# Working with System when there is No internet

Tags: c#, sql-server, angular, offline

I have an application that works as a Point of sale(POS). It's designed on angular with mssql as the backend. Now its hosted on a server. It is currently working in a restaurant but sometimes since the restaurant has a makeshift internet, It keeps disconnecting etc. Is there a way to make the thing work without internet. At least just to take the order and then when the internet is one it connects to the cloud and updates the DB.

Comment: The short answer is "Yes", but its way too broad question for here. I recommend investigating database replication and synchronisation.

Comment: Convert your angular app into a PWA ( Progressive Web App ). They are designed to work offline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending about what you must do. Yes you can install the server in a local machine and you start your angular in your local machine, but you need to use a local machine server if you use  POS to take orders. You can create a private connection with a server and connect all subject to this connect. The customers for pay must be connect to internert.

Comment: Doesn't it seem reasonable that the app instead would store data in local storage of the web browser when offline and syncronize it with the back end when it becomes online?

Comment: @mortb risky because all it takes is the browser to be shutdown, or the computer turned off to lose the cached transations. POS system architecture is well known and the problem already solved many times in many different ways.

Comment: @Dale Burrell yes you're right. I think it would be better to buy the POS software. It needs to be well tested. Not sure how the OP works, but if you write it as a single freelance developer you might well be personally resposible for any money lost due to bugs